# How do you set the port for ChromeDriver in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob

As some background, I'm playing around with BrowserMob proxy and I am getting blocked by the port settings. So I'd like to know how to set a port by myself.

```
 Server srv = new Server(@"C:\BMob\browsermob\bin\browsermob-proxy.bat");
 srv.Start();
 Client cln = srv.CreateProxy();
 cln.NewHar("BOWZA"); 
 ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
 Proxy  seleniumProxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = cln.SeleniumProxy };
 co.Proxy = seleniumProxy;
 ChromeDriver cDriver = new ChromeDriver(co);
// What do I do now...?
```

I just failed to find anything documenting this, sorry

Comment: Know this is old but where does Server and Client come from as in Visual Studio it the namespace can't be found.  Any reference I add seems incorrect.  Like the server.Stop() objective isn't found but the Start is in theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
ChromeDriverService service= ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(DRIVER_PATH);
service.Port = <PORT>;
IWebDriver WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(service);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I'm using webDriverManager as well

```
    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(DesiredPortNumber).build();
```

Then use it as a parameter when initializing new driver

```
new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService , BrowserOptionsManager.getChromeOptions());
```