# How to capture network traffic with selenium

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting a new Django project, I'm trying to capture the network traffic with Selenium.

I have already achieved this objective with Selenium-wire (MITM Proxy), but Django doesn't like to work with selenium-wire ( must start the server with "--nothreading --noreload", connection bug... ).
I'm looking for achieve this with modern solutions, like parsing the network devtools of firefox directly or with a firefox addons.
I'm using Firefox Geckodriver for my test.

```py
    for x in range(0, 10):
                profile = profile_firefox()
                options = options_firefox()
                driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path='/Users/*****/Desktop/selenium-master/headless_browser/geckodriver')
                try:
                        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
                        driver.set_window_size(randint(1024, 2060), randint(1024, 4100))
                        time.sleep(randint(3,10))
                        driver.get(url)
                        wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                        time.sleep(randint(8,10))
                        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button"):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button").click()
                                del driver.requests
                                time.sleep(randint(8,10))
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button").click()
                                time.sleep(randint(10,20))
                                for request in driver.requests:
                                        if request.path == "https://api.*********.**/*******/*******":
                                                request_api = request
                                                raw = str(request_api.body)
                                                request_api = raw.split(('b\''))
                                                payload_raw = request_api[1]
                                                payload = payload_raw[:-1]
                                                if payload:
                                                        header = request.headers
                                                        time.sleep(8)
                                                        break

                except:
                        print("Houston on a eu un probleme")
                        firefox_closing(driver)
```

Edit :

```py
def profile_firefox():
        profile = FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
        profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
        profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", firefox_init())
        profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
        profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', 'localhost')
        profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
        profile.set_preference("driver.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
        profile.update_preferences()
        return profile
```

Test 2 with Socks,HTTP,SSL configuration :

```py
server = Server('/Users/*****/Desktop/selenium-master/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy')
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
proxy.selenium_proxy()#Dont understand what it does ???
port = int(proxy.port)

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', firefox_init())
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', 'localhost')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', 'localhost')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', port)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', 'localhost')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', port)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)
profile.set_preference('driver.privatebrowsing.autostart', True)
profile.update_preferences()
```

It seems Http proxy override the socks configuration...

Thanks a lot if you have any clue or advice about my code or solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsermob is the right way.

I must understand how browsermob works and tor too.
For Tor you must enable the HTTPTunnelPort configuration like this.

```
tor --HTTPTunnelPort 8088
```

And configure browsermob to use it.

```
proxy_params = {'httpProxy': 'localhost:8088', 'httpsProxy': 'localhost:8088'}
proxy_b = server.create_proxy(params=proxy_params)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The BrowserMob Proxy is no longer maintained since 2016. I'd suggest using the BrowserUp proxy fork at https://github.com/browserup/browserup-proxy. It is a drop-in replacement and works with the python browsermob client.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a proxy to catch the network traffic. [browsermob-proxy](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) works well with selenium in Python. You need to download browsermob executable before. This is the piece of code with Firefox :

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver

server = Server('path_to_executable')
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
proxy.new_har("file_name", options={'captureHeaders': True, 'captureContent': True})
driver.get("your_url")
proxy.wait_for_traffic_to_stop(1, 60)
for ent in proxy.har['log']['entries']:
    print(ent)

server.stop()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have edited my first post, I'm using Tor to rotate my IP through the 9050 port, in my Firefox profile.
Is it possible to combine your solution with my configuration ?

Comment: I don't know if it is compatible I never used Tor with this. Maybe there will be some port/host redirections to do between the proxies.

Comment: I'm stuck, when I set manually in the profile configuration a socks,http,ssl proxy the socks proxy doesn't work.... 
I'm looking for a solution like this one, if profile configuration can't work [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270270/how-do-you-set-the-port-for-chromedriver-in-selenium/38270926#38270926)

Answer (score 6):

Python has a package called selenium-wire. You can use that package to capture the network traffics and also validate them. selenium-wire is an extended version of selenium will all the capabilities of selenium along with extra API to capture the network and validate. following is a link of an article
https://sensoumya94.medium.com/validate-network-requests-using-selenium-and-python-3da5be112f7b

following is the repository of the package

https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire

Sample code -

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Go to the Google home page
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

Comment: OP stated that selenium wire does not work well with Django