# Python / Selenium - how to catch network requests by the site?

Tags: python, selenium

When using the dev console on Chrome and going to the network tab, i can get the video streams on the site by looking for requests with an m3u8 url. How can i get this data in Selenium, without using third party tools like a proxy - maybe selenium has ways to access the developer console?

I see similar questions with no answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318066/how-get-all-network-requests-using-python-selenium-webdriver), but i cant imagine that its not possible

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture network traffic with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705650/how-to-capture-network-traffic-with-selenium)

Comment: i saw this question, but i was hoping for a solution that works with just selenium - after all selenium uses a web browser, and if i can open the dev console myself, surely there must be a way to do these steps in selenium? before i use another module i think id just make selenium do the clicks / hotkeys to open the console, but i was hoping that selenium has something for this implemented

Comment: Unfortunately Selenium doesn't support this, we need to use another package...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by passing `options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")` and then automatically clicking in the network tab with pyautogui