# Selenium python - How to capture network traffic responses

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

The issue I seem to be having is that I cannot find any way to access the network traffic responses in firefox using selenium (Python). I know that solutions exist for the Chrome webdriver, but for my case I need to use the Firefox version. I've been trying to figure this out for like have a day and I'm pulling out my hair at this point. Is there any way to get these responses?

Answer (score 0):

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705650/how-to-capture-network-traffic-with-selenium) using browsermob-proxy. Not exactly what I wanted, but it does give all the requests and all the responses.

Comment: how to use it in linux as I am not able work with it.