# SpecFlow, Selenium, NUnit, Parallelization: ChromeDriver Windows from two different NUnit Tests, keep having unexplained relation

Tags: c#, selenium, parallel-processing, nunit, specflow

I have a `selenium-webdriver-di.cs` file like this:

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using BoDi;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class WebDriverHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;
    private static Dictionary<string, ChromeDriver> drivers = new Dictionary<string, ChromeDriver>();
    private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
    private FeatureContext _featureContext;

    public WebDriverHooks(IObjectContainer container, ScenarioContext scenarioContext, FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        this.container = container;
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        _featureContext = featureContext;
    }
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void CreateWebDriver(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BeforeFeature");
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        drivers[featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title] = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void InjectWebDriver(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        if (!featureContext.ContainsKey("driver"))
        {
            featureContext.Add("driver", drivers[featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title]);
        }
    }
    [AfterFeature]
    public static void DeleteWebDriver(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        ((IWebDriver)featureContext["driver"]).Close();
        ((IWebDriver)featureContext["driver"]).Quit();
    }
```

And then in each of my .cs files that contains the step definitions, I have constructors like this:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PfizerWorld2019.CommunityCreationTestAutomation.SeleniumUtils;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace PfizerWorld2019
{
    [Binding]
    public class SharePointListAssets
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver driver;
        public SharePointListAssets(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
            this.driver = (IWebDriver)featureContext["driver"];
        }
    }
}
```

And then I'm using the `driver` variable in all the functions of the class. Lastly I have a file that I called `Assembly.cs`, where I put this for NUnit fixture level parallelization:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Which in SpecFlow's terms means parallelization on the Feature level(1 .feature file = 1 Nunit Test = 1 Nunit Fixture)

If I run my tests serially, they work fine.

But if I run 2 tests in parallel, any two tests, always something funny happens. For example: the first Chromedriver window tries to click an element and it clicks it if and only when the second Chromedriver window (that is running a different test) renders the exact same part of the website. But it sends the click to the correct window (the first one).

I have tried:

1. To use the `IObjectContainer` interface and then do `containers[featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title].RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(drivers[featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title])` in the `InjectWebDriver` function
2. To use `Thread.CurrentThread.ToString()` instead of `featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title` for indexing
3. To do `featureContext.Add(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title + "driver", new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)` instead of `drivers[featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title] = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);` in the `CreateWebDriver` function.

I just do not understand what allows this "sharing". Since `FeatureContext` is used for everything related to driver spawning and destruction, how can two chromedrivers talk with each other?

**Update**: I tried the driver initialization & sharing like this:

```
[BeforeFeature]
public static void CreateWebDriver(FeatureContext featureContext)
{
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    chromeOptions.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:/ChromeProfiles/Profile" + uniqueIndex);
    WebdriverSafeSharing.setWebDriver(TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkerId, new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
}
```

and I made a webdriver-safe-sharing.cs file like this:

```
class WebdriverSafeSharing
{
    private static Dictionary<string, IWebDriver> webdrivers = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
    public static void setWebDriver(string driver_identification, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        webdrivers[driver_identification] = driver;
    }
    public static IWebDriver getWebDriver(string driver_identification)
    {
        return webdrivers[driver_identification];
    }
}
```

and then in each step definition function, I'm just calling `WebdriverSafeSharing.getWebDriver(TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkerId)` without any involvement of the FeatureContext. And I'm still getting the same issue. Notice how I'm doing `chromeOptions.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:/ChromeProfiles/Profile" + uniqueIndex);` because I'm also starting to not trust that chromedriver itself is thread safe. But even that did not help.

**Update 2**: It tried an even more paranoid `webdriver-safe-sharing.cs` class:

```
class WebdriverSafeSharing
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>> webdrivers = new Dictionary<string, ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>>();
    private static int port = 7000;
    public static void setWebDriver(string driver_identification)
    {
        lock (webdrivers)
        {
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.Port = port;
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
            ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> driver =
            new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>(() =>
            {
                return new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
            });
            webdrivers[driver_identification] = driver;
            port += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    public static IWebDriver getWebDriver(string driver_identification)
    {
        return webdrivers[driver_identification].Value;
    }
```

It has a lock, a Threadlocal and unique port. It still does not work. Exact same issues.

**Update 3**: If I run two separate Visual Studio instances and I run 1 test for each, it works. Or by having two identical projects run side by side
[image]

and then selecting to run the tests in parallel:

[image]

Comment: One bit of confusion: "1 .feature file = 1 Nunit Test = 1 Nunit Fixture." An NUnit Test is not the same as an NUnit Fixture. It would help to have a doc reference that describes how SpecFlow maps features and scenarios to NUnit entities.

Comment: @charlie I was not able to find any such doc in the specflow documentation. Your comment that 1 Nunit fixture != 1 Nunit test bothers me. If 1 Nunit test contains more than 1 fixtures, wouldn't that be a problem for me? However, the Specflow auto-generated code creates 1 fixture per feature file and then Nunit treats each feature file as a test, that's why I made this 3ple equation

Comment: Taxonomy of Tests in NUnit...

Comment: NUnit uses the term Test to mean an kind of test, simple or compound. Simple (single) tests are Test Cases, represented by a method and optional arguments. There are various kinds of suites, one of which is TestFixture, represented as a single instance of a class, created with or without constructor arguments. Your example TestFixture contains two TestCases.. I guess your use of the word "test" simply means something else in that case, so we're probably both "right" but when dealing with NUnit, it's good to know NUnit terminology.

Comment: What it comes down to is that you are ultimately running an NUnit test through the NUnit framework, which is entirely ignorant of Features, Scenarios, Feature Contexts, etc. It's too bad there isn't public documentation of how SpecFlow translates it's own concepts to NUnit so that a wider range of people (like me!) could actually help with problems like this.

Comment: @Charlie SpecFlow does have this: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html but it does not say much about NUnit.

However, here is an auto-generated code file by SpecFlow from my project for a feature file that includes NUnit decorations, don't know if it is of any insight:
https://gist.github.com/TasosDhm/83dfe370d8498eef4e202058a36ed046

Comment: Oh my goodness. I think I just realized the problem. The port number with which you start ChromeDriver. Each instance of ChromeDriver should run on a separate port. Which ports are your ChromeDriver instances running on?

Comment: I'm not specifying the port anywhere, Chromedriver starts a session on its own random port on its own. I did try to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270926/1238675 but it didn't help. Now I'm thinking i might have not done this in a thread safe way. How can i set the port in a thread safe manner?

Comment: @Greg I added an Update2 in the question with a (thread safe?) port implementation, no luck

Comment: I'm starting to believe that Selenium clicks are not thread safe. Or something with the webdriver context, I don't know

Comment: It works if I run the two tests from two separate Visual Studio instances and with the same Chrome Port. Or by having two identical projects open simultaneously in Visual Studio

Comment: @Tasos Thanks for the file. As you already know, it gives partial info, since we don't know a lot of things abut what happens inside SpecFlow. Experimenting, as you are doing, is probably the only way to find out. If it's looking like it might be a Selenium problem, and you have time, try a straight NUnit (no SpecFlow) test using Selenium.

Comment: @charlie I found the issue. It had forgotten that i had an old file with static wrappers in the code... However many things where noted in this effort and I posted them in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that all the selenium API actions were wrapped in `static` methods written by me. It was a class in a file that I wrote many weeks ago for code re-usability. However not being used into working with parallel programming in C#, I was honestly not aware anymore that these methods were declared `static`. I am now running 20 parallel workers on Selenium Grid.

However I'm placing here some important notes to be aware of, if one faces parallelization issues with NUnit, SpecFlow and Selenium

- The initialization of the WebDriver must be done in the `[BeforeFeauture]`-bound method if the goal is feature-level and not scenario-level parallelization.
- The initialization of the WebDriver must be thread safe. What I did is that I used a static Dictionary that is indexed by the `FeatureContext.FeatureInfo.Title` that contains the WebDrivers
- chromedriver is thread safe. There is no need unique data-dir folders or unique ports or unique chromedriver file names. The `--headless`  and `--no-sandbox` arguments that one might be interested in have not caused me any issues with parallelization (either with Selenium Grid or simple single multi-core machine parallelization). Basically don't blame the chromedriver.
- For injecting the webdriver, do use the `IObjectContainer` interface in the `[BeforeScenario]`-bound method. It is great and safe.
- Dispose the driver in the `[AfterFeature]`-bound method with `driver.Dispose()` so that you don't have zombie processes. This helped me with Selenium Grid, because when I was using `driver.Close()` and `driver.Quit()`, the nodes would not kill the processes after the latter were done.
- For `NUnit` with `[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]` enabled, all the scenarios within a `.feature` file run within the same `FeatureContext` and therefore the scenarios are `FeatureContext`-safe. This means that you can trust the `FeatureContext` for sharing data between scenarios within the same `.feature` file.
- The `[BeforeFeature]` hook is being called only once per `.feature` file (as one would logically assume). So if you have x `.feature` files, the hook will be called x times during a test run.
- As the Specflow Documentation says, for feature-level parallelization either `NUnit` or `xUnit` should be used as the test framework. However the `NUnit` has the benefit that it provides out of the box ordering for the tests, by alphabetical sort order. This is particularly useful if you want to have two scenarios run in sequence within the same feature file. i.e. putting a number in front of each scenario title will ensure their order during execution. `xUnit` does not support this natively and it looked like a difficult goal to achieve from searching around.
- Specflow is more "friendly" in terms of parallelization, for scenario-level parallelization. This is why the `Specflow+ Runner` test framework by SpecFlow runs scenario levels in parallel. it looks like the whole philosophy of SpecFlow (I wouldn't say BDD yet) is to have independent scenarios. This doesn't mean of course that you cannot have very nice feature-level parallelization by using the other test frameworks. Just putting it out there as a heads up for someone reading this while drafting a strategy for writing feature files.

Comment: Nice summary. Be aware that alphabetical ordering of NUnit test cases is pretty much an unintentional "feature", which could disappear. It's better to use the Order attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that you are stashing the IWebDriver object in the FeatureContext. The FeatureContext is created and reused for each scenario in a feature. While on the surface it appears safe for [running tests in parallel](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html) using NUnit (which does not run scenarios in the same feature in parallel), my hunch is that this is not as safe as you think.

Instead, initialize and destroy the IWebDriver object with each *scenario*, rather than feature. The ScenarioContext should be thread safe, since it is created once for each scenario, and is only used for one scenario. I would recommend using dependency injection instead:

```
[Binding]
public class WebDriverHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;

    public WebDriverHooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateWebDriver()
    {
        var driver = // Initialize your web driver here

        container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void DestroyWebDriver()
    {
        var driver = container.Resolve<IWebDriver>();

        // Take screenshot if you want...

        // Dispose of the web driver
        driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then add a constructor argument to your step definition classes to pass the IWebDriver:

```
[Binding]
public class FooSteps
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public FooSteps(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    // step definitions...
}
```

Comment: If FeatureContext is not thread safe, then that's a problem. But restarting the driver from ScenarioContext doesn't help me very much, it would delay the execution of the feature and also I would have to add it manually in the code for many scenarios. I might just give it a shot to prove an alternative, but I also keep wondering if I can do something on the feature level so that I don't have the issue

Comment: @Tasos: The Dictionary you are using in your solution is also not thread-safe either.

Comment: You mean because it's static? Doesn't the indexing that I'm doing solve that? (Either by featutecontext title or thread name)

Comment: I have attempted with no Dictionary and only feature context btw and I got the same result (bullet point 3 in the question)

Comment: driver management through scenario context also introduces problems with scenario outlines. I don't want to restart the driver in each scenario outline

Comment: @Tasos: I have another idea. I might post a second answer, actually.

Comment: Something is up with the constructors of the files that are assigning the drivers. Maybe those are created only once i don't know. Or it is the featureContext that is causing  the problem. 

I am now working on an implementation where I have a global class dictionary of drivers with a getter and a setter. The dictionary's keys are the Thread.Current.Name. But this doesn't work either! Even though I have a local driver variable in every single step definition that grabs the driver from the global class using the Thread.Current.Name

Comment: I updated the question with another attempt that I made, with no success unfortunately and I don't understand what the problem with it is